# LEFT OUTER JOIN in sqldf with WHERE and HAVING clauses

Tags: r, sqldf

I have two data frames in R and I would like to conditionally merge them on `id` and `day`. The merge is that the `right` variables merged to the `left` variables be as new/fresh/recent as possible, but must be at least three days old.

But, if there isn't a match in `right` to my `id`-`date` pair in `left` I'd still like to retain them. My study has two parts, so I don't want to drop the `id`-`day` observations just because they're not complete.

Can I do this in one `sqldf` step? My current approach requires an additional base R `merge`.

```
left <- data.frame(id=rep(1:5, each=10),
                   day=rep(1:10, times=5),
                   x=rnorm(5*10))
right <- data.frame(id=rep(1:2, each=21),
                   day=rep(-10:10, times=2),
                   y=rnorm(2*21))
combined <- sqldf("SELECT L.id, L.day, L.x, R.y
                  FROM left L LEFT OUTER JOIN right R
                  ON (L.id = R.id)
                  WHERE ((L.day - R.day) >= 3)
                  GROUP BY L.id, L.day
                  HAVING (R.day = MAX(R.day))")
combined                  

combined.2 <- merge(left, combined, all=TRUE)
combined.2
```

Comment: Have you tried to do this with `data.table` package?

Comment: @bartektartanus - No, but I'm wide open to `data.table` (I've never used it, but heard good things). I don't use SQL much either, it was just my first thought for a conditional merge.

Comment: @bartektartanus - Also, in my actual data this is _very_ slow. About 4 minutes per merge, even if I follow GG's speed guide in [example 4i](https://code.google.com/p/sqldf/#Example_4._Join).

Comment: data.table is faster than data.frame, so you should totally use this :) In a minute I will wrote some answer for your problem, stay cool :)

Comment: @bartektartanus - Thanks! GG answered the question as asked, but I'm still interested if there's a faster approach.

Comment: @bartektartanus, I just want to let you know that I have added a `data.table` answer..

Comment: @Uwe thanks! Looks like "in a minute" means six years :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try nesting the select statements like this:

```
sqldf("SELECT * from left
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, L.day, L.x, R.y
                  FROM left L LEFT OUTER JOIN right R
                  USING (id)
                  WHERE ((L.day - R.day) >= 3)
                  GROUP BY L.id, L.day
                  HAVING (R.day = MAX(R.day))) 
       USING (id, day, x)")
```

This could also be done as follows.  It uses the fact that if max is used then the other values on the same resulting row are guaranteed to come from the same original row as the max.  This is an extension to SQL that SQLite provides.

```
sqldf("select max(R.day) as maxRday, L.*, R.y
  from left L left outer join right R
  on L.id = R.id and L.day - R.day >= 3
  group by L.id, L.day")[-1]
```

Comment: Why `LEFT` then `LEFT JOIN`? Thanks!

Comment: The first LEFT is the name of the data frame.  I have changed it to lower case to make the case consistent with the remainder of the statement.

Comment: Ah! Thanks! (I guess not the best example on my part.)

Comment: That's a good solution, I struggled using ```HAVING``` and ```WHERE``` commands in a single script. Your code helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With version 1.9.8 (on CRAN 25 Nov 2016), `data.table` gained the ability to perform *non-equi joins*. This feature wasn't available in 2014 when [bartektartanus promised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22879678/left-outer-join-in-sqldf-with-where-and-having-clauses#comment34914008_22879678)  to post a `data.table` answer.

Now, in 2020, with a delay of 6 years here is a `data.table` answer:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(right)[, join_day := day + 3L][
  setDT(left), on = .(id, join_day <= day), .(x = last(x), y = last(y)), by = .EACHI][
    , setnames(.SD, "join_day", "day")]
```

which returns

> ```
>     id day  x  y
>  1:  1   1  1  2
>  2:  1   2  2  2
>  3:  1   3  3  3
>  4:  2   1  4  6
>  5:  2   2  5  7
>  6:  2   3  6  7
>  7:  3   1  7 13
>  8:  3   2  8 14
>  9:  3   3  9 15
> 10:  4   1 10 NA
> 11:  4   2 11 NA
> 12:  4   3 12 NA
> ```

for the modified sample data

```
left <- data.table(id = rep(1:4, each=3),
                   day = rep(1:3, times=4),
                   x = 1:(3*4))
right <- data.table(id = c(rep(1:2, each=5L), rep(3, 9L)),
                    day = c(seq(-4L, 4L, 2L), seq(-3L, 5L, 2L), -4:4))[, y := seq_along(id)]
```

where

```
left
```

> ```
>     id day  x
>  1:  1   1  1
>  2:  1   2  2
>  3:  1   3  3
>  4:  2   1  4
>  5:  2   2  5
>  6:  2   3  6
>  7:  3   1  7
>  8:  3   2  8
>  9:  3   3  9
> 10:  4   1 10
> 11:  4   2 11
> 12:  4   3 12
> ```

and

```
right
```

> ```
>     id day  y
>  1:  1  -4  1
>  2:  1  -2  2
>  3:  1   0  3
>  4:  1   2  4
>  5:  1   4  5
>  6:  2  -3  6
>  7:  2  -1  7
>  8:  2   1  8
>  9:  2   3  9
> 10:  2   5 10
> 11:  3  -4 11
> 12:  3  -3 12
> 13:  3  -2 13
> 14:  3  -1 14
> 15:  3   0 15
> 16:  3   1 16
> 17:  3   2 17
> 18:  3   3 18
> 19:  3   4 19
> ```